# In Swift OOP design, how do I arrange a commonly-used class?

Tags: swift, oop, swift2

I am new to Swift and OOP. For example, I have a class that manages the system-wide configurations.

```
class system_conf {
    init()
    getValue1()
    getValue2()
    ...
    setValue1()
    setValue2()
    ...
    reloadValues()
    activateX()
    activeteY()
    ...
}
```

This class should have only one instance and many other classes will use it. What's the recommended way for this case?

- Should I pass around this instance?
- Should I consider to use Singleton?
- Should I use static functions directly?
- Should I create a global instance, so every other class can access it directly?
- or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your class is a configuration class. If you intend to pass it to a bunch of classes, you should wonder if you need to write unit tests for them.

If so, assuming you are either using a singleton or static methods or a global var, take a moment to think about how you would mock this configuration class for each of your tests. It's not easy, is it?

If [your class is a kind of mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern), a global var or static methods are fine (or any other alternative you suggested). However, in your case, it would be better to pass your object in any initializer/constructor of each class using it. Then, testing would definitely be easier. Also, passing it via an interface is even better: you can mock it super easily (mock up libraries mostly work with interfaces only).

So there is no unique answer to your question. It is just a matter of compromises and scaling. If your app is small, any of the method you listed above is perfectly fine. However, if you app tends to get bigger, a proxy solution would be better for maintainability and testability.

If you fancy reading, you should glance at [this article from Misko Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/), [especially this chapter](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/).